# Minecraft 1.12.1 wont update

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, pc

It loads forever and then suddenly this Message comes up:

> Failed to download file. fastutil-7.1.0.jar
>   Name: fastutil-7.1.0.jar
>   URL: https://libraries.minecraft.net/it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/7.1.0/fastutil-7.1.0.jar
>   Error details: Request error -101: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
>   Filename on disk: 65b4-f7d6-9746-602e
>   Path: C:\Users\vetle\AppData\Local\Temp\65b4-f7d6-9746-602e
>   Exists: file

I have tried suggestions from this [thread](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/310983/minecraft-wont-update-to-1-12), but to no avail.
I don't have any mods either

Comment: I dont have any mods though, i literally downloaded it straight from minecraft.net

Comment: That's my mistake - I didn't realise fastutil was part of base Minecraft

Comment: @vsdalby Does Sumurai8's answer solve your problem? If yes, please click on "accept answer". If no, please give more details to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` suggests that there are connection problems with the server. If the update just came out, it could be that the servers are overloaded and unable to process your update request at this time. Try to update at a different time.

If the problem persists, make sure that your antivirus software is not actively blocking the download, and that your firewall is allowing the connection to be made. This could also be the modem/firewall on the router itself.